# CakePHP 2 autocompletion in PhpStorm 2016

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, cakephp-2.0, phpstorm

I'm trying to move from NetBeans to PhpStorm for working on a rather large CakePHP 2 application. The main problem I'm having is that autocompletion for Models and (Custom) ViewHelpers requires specific comments in my files.

Comments like:

```
/**
 * @property $Somemodel $Somemodel
 */
```

or in a View file, to enable autocompletion for ViewHelpers:

```
/**
 * @var this $View
 */
```

NetBeans has a plugin that offers CakePHP support, including autocompletion; PhpStorm does have a CakePHP plugin (CakeStorm), but offers no integrated autocomplete support.

What I'm trying to avoid is having to add these comments to ALL of my Controllers, Models and View. Next to that, the `@var this View` comment does not support custom ViewHelpers, which is something I heavily rely on in my application.

Is there a way to make this more 'programmer friendly'? CakePHP 2 has the `$uses = array('Modelone', 'Modeltwo');`. Why can't PhpStorm understand that these are Classes that need to be autocompleted?

Comment: *"Why can't PhpStorm understand that these are Classes that need to be autocompleted?"* Because that would require PhpStorm devs to have **special** parser/completion just for CakePHP framework (which they have not done for any of the frameworks around). If anything -- it has to be implemented by CakePHP-specific plugin (the aforementioned CakeStorm, for example) which requires decent bit of work to be done to analyse your PHP code and understand that here these classes/models/helpers are used and on that file/class -- another helpers/models  with different sets of methods/fields.

Comment: @LazyOne I know this isn't supposed to be 'baked' into PHPStorm (pun intended). It would either require a dedicated plugin, like we both implied, or a smart way of adding these PHPDoc comments to my files. I'm not asking PHPStorm to make this for me. The 'decent bit of work analysing my code' is already done by PHPStorm, it already analyses complete projects, it just doesn't know where to look in a CakePHP 2 codebase and that's exactly my problem.

Comment: *"it just doesn't know where to look in a CakePHP 2 codebase and that's exactly my problem."* That's not exactly what I meant. I mean this line: `$uses = array('Modelone', 'Modeltwo');` -- for PhpStorm it's just a line of code and nothing more. It should be up to CakeStorm plugin to understand what this line means for CakePHP and offer additional methods/fields when code completion is required.

Comment: PhpStorm can only work with PHPDoc hints (e.g. `/** @var View $this */` on view files etc) and PHPDoc is quite limited and does not allow to describe all possible scenarios/techniques used by different frameworks. Plus, PhpStorm follows PHPDoc and requires that PHPDoc precedes actual usage (e.g. `@property` can only be used in PHPDoc that belong to that class which makes impossible to have any additional `@property` declarations for that class but located elsewhere -- could be useful if original class does not have enough docs and you cannot edit source class).

Comment: So overall: it's either done via PHPDoc comments (which you may need to place in quite few files) .. or better (but more difficult/time consuming to implement) via framework-specific support plugins (e.g. the one for Symfony is considered the best example and most feature rich (at least among those that I have worked with)).